# How to know what a function takes as parameter what does it return after adding a DLL file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dll, webapi

I'm working on Web API C#, So one of my colleague have implemented a function
that do some calculation that I need to use as well.

He will share my the DLL file for that. I know I need to add the DLL in my project
but how can I know exactly what functions are available in that DLL file
,their names , their input parameter and output parameter?

Comment: Functions aren´t available in a DLL - classes are, which **contain** functions. If you don´t know the classes within an assembly, use the object-browser in VS.

Comment: In VS you can double click the library in the solution explorer, it will open the object explorer in the right spot (you can then see all namespaces, classes, interfaces, methods & properties, etc)

Comment: Your colleague should also provide some kind of documentation or guide on how the DLL is expected to be used. Otherwise it's just a guessgame.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

- Open **Developer Command Prompt for VS**
- Type **ildasm**. It will open a window.
- Go to: *File*. Select the DLL you want